# How to check if a div is out of his father or not with plain JS

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, I have something like this:

```
<div id='father' style='width: 100%; height: 100px; position:absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;overflow:hidden;'>
    <div id='box' style='width: 50px; height: 50px;'></div>
</div>
<script>
function FrandomBoxPos(elem){
    cuadrante = rand(1,4);
    if (cuadrante == 1){
        elem.style.top = "-"+rand(100, 200)+"px";
        elem.style.left = rand(1, document.body.offsetWidth)+"px";
    } else if (cuadrante == 2){
        elem.style.top = rand(1, document.body.offsetHeight)+"px";
        elem.style.left = rand(-300, (document.body.offsetWidth*-1)-300)+"px";
    } else if (cuadrante == 3){
        elem.style.top = rand(document.body.offsetHeight, document.getElementById('DcontenidoSubmenu').offsetHeight+100)+"px";
        elem.style.left = rand(1, document.body.offsetWidth)+"px";
    } else if (cuadrante == 4){
        elem.style.top = rand(1, document.body.offsetHeight)+"px";
        elem.style.left = rand(document.body.offsetWidth+400, document.body.offsetWidth+600)+"px";
    }
}
FrandomBoxPos(document.getElementById('box'));
</script>
```

Sometimes, after I run FrandomBoxPos I can see 'box' into his father (I shouldn't). So if I could check if 'box' is out of 'father' I could make something like:

```
while isOutOf('box', 'father') == false:
    FrandomBoxPos(document.getElementById('box'));
```

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/bnnWLwdY
I can't paste it jsFiddle because doesn't work there.
When you leave the mouse on any of the "section" buttons and a BOX is not moving and NOT in place (into the red borders) is when something is wrong...

Comment: What do you mean "I can see 'box' into his father?"

Comment: Tip: DIV isn't a self closing tag.

Comment: @ExplosionPills overflow: hidden css propety on 'father' doesn't allow to see his children tags if they are out of 'father'. For example, if a children has top: 200px; you wouldn't see that div.

Answer (score 1):

```
if((child.posX > dad.posX && child.posX < dad.posX + dad.width) || (child.posX + child.width > dad.posX && child.posX + child.width < dad.posX + dad.width) ) {
   //it is in horizontal boundaries
     if((child.posY > dad.posY && child.posY < dad.posY + dad.width) || (child.posY + child.width > dad.posY && child.posY + child.width < dad.posY + dad.width) ) {
   //child overlaps parent
    }
}
```

I think this should work..

Comment: Didn't worked. [Image link](http://gyazo.com/7edcb16c283dd37e90dc8301dd885b7f.png) the box ended in "won" is inside the box, I called the function with your conditionals and the console.log didn't appear

Comment: could you create a working jsfiddle where we can test it out?

Comment: I see the image but I need a link with the code to try and fix it. copy/paste your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Check the question, I added a link.